# preg_replace() optional pattern matching

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to do some pattern matching on PHP using preg_match(). I want my users to enter an amount from their mobile device. so if they wanna enter 50.50, they could enter 50*50 (the asterisk here is the actual asterisk button on the phone). so i want to check the input for some validations.  mainly 
1. all the inputs have to be digits (excluding the asterisk)
2. the number of decimal points after the asterisk should be two.
3. the decimal digits are optional. that means a user can enter 50 or 50.50 both should be valid.

so far what i have is this. `if( preg_match( "_\d{1,6}(\*\d{2})_" , $input) {//do something}`. this code works partially, the problem is i cant make the sub-pattern search optional. i looked into the manual but couldn't find anything. i need help thank you

Comment: `+1` for using a non-standard delimiter. More people need to be aware of the fact that PHP can do this XD Personally, though, I use parentheses because they come in matching pairs and therefore never need escaping "just because it's the delimiter".

Comment: I dont think its the delimiterthat has the problem.

Comment: I didn't say it was. I just found it commendable that you knew about using a different delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Add `?` after the `)` to make it optional. `?` used as a quantifier means "zero or one" - ie. optional.

As a side-note, I'm not aware of any mobile devices that have a browser but don't let you type a `.` easily...

Comment: Cellphones from the 90's probably.

Comment: thanks for the reply. actually its not a web app. its a USSD software script. i tried your suggestion but it still passes inputs which have more than two digits after the decimal point(asterisk)

Comment: Ah, right, use `^` and `$` at the start and end (just inside the delimiters) to match the whole string.

Comment: okay i have tried both your suggestions and it doesn't seem to be working. can you post the code (that you explained) ?

Comment: `"(^\d{1,6}(\*\d{2})?$)"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array("50.50", "50", "50*50", "4");

foreach($array as $number)
{
if (preg_match('/^[\d]{2}(\.|\*)?([\d]{2})?/sim', $number)) {
    echo $number ." VALID ";
} else {
    echo $number ." INVALID ";
    //Do something with the invalid number
}
}
```

OUTPUTS: `50.50 VALID 50 VALID 50*50 VALID 4 INVALID`

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/icRGgr)